# Solving Boolean functions and changing to simplified form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How is the truth table for $(p \lor q) \lor (p \land r)$ e same as the truth table for $p \lor q$?
Using formular such as De Morgans n etc..
And can anyone tell me how to start of with this type of questions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
(p \lor q) \lor (p \land r) = ((p \lor q) \lor p) \land ((p \lor q) \lor r)
$$

by the [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} (p \lor q) \lor (p \land r) &\equiv ((p \lor q) \lor p) \land ((p \lor q) \lor r)\tag{1}\\ \\
&\equiv (p\lor q \lor p) \land (p \lor q \lor r)\tag{2}\\ \\ 
&\equiv (p \lor q) \land ((p\lor q)\lor r)\tag{3}\\ \\
&\equiv p\lor q\tag{4}\end{align}$$

Comment: The last step is by absorption: $a \land (a \lor b)] \equiv a$. Let me know if you "get" that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one derivation:
$$\begin{align}
 (p\lor q)\lor(p\land r)&\equiv(q\lor p)\lor(p\land r) &\text{commutativity}\\
 &\equiv q\lor (p\lor(p\land r)) &\text{associativity}\\
 &\equiv q\lor p &\text{absorption}\\
 &\equiv p\lor q &\text{commutativity}\\
\end{align}$$
I'd love to provide a simple algorithm you could use to generate such derivations for any initial expression, but I'm afraid there simply isn't one. It does, though, become easier with practice.